# EF first database change connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I have server with some databases that have the same schema. I use EF6 Database/Model First code and I do not want to create deterrent `DbContext` for them. for example my generated `DbContext` is :

```
public partial class TEST_Rev5_FINALEntities : DbContext
{
    public TEST_Rev5_FINALEntities()
        : base("name=TEST_Rev5_FINALEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Header> tbl_Headers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Output> tbl_Output { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Run> tbl_Run { get; set; }
}
```

and I created a partial class to set the connection string

```
public partial class TEST_Rev5_FINALEntities : DbContext 
{
    public TEST_Rev5_FINALEntities(DbConnection dbConnection)
        : base(dbConnection, true)
    {
    }
}
```

And I have the following method to create the connection with deterrent connection string:

```
public DbConnection GetConnectionString()
{
    DbConnection conn;
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = DataSource,
        IntegratedSecurity = false,
        UserID = User,
        Password = Password,
        MultipleActiveResultSets = true
    };

    SqlConnectionFactory sqlConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(sqlConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
    conn = sqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DatabaseName);

    return conn;
}
```

Finally I try to run it like this:

```
using (var context = new TEST_Rev5_FINALEntities(_dal.Connector.GetConnectionString()))
{
    return context.tbl_Headers.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

but I get this error :

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException
>   HResult=0x80131509   Message=The context is being used in Code First
>   mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either
>   Database First or Model First development.

How can I do it?

Comment: Could you post the pattern you use in your connectionsting?

Comment: Data Source=gsql;Initial Catalog=TEST_Rev5_FINAL;Integrated Security=False;User ID=***;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True I guess this is the problem. thank you nozzleman

Comment: Refer to Marting Zikmunds answer. This it should be correct

Comment: Oh, I am surprised the metadata portion is not there :-O

Answer (score 1):

The behavior EF uses depends on the way your connection string looks. If it includes a `metadata` attribute like this:

```
metadata=res://*/model.csdl|res://*/model.ssdl|res://*/model.msl;
```

It will presume you are using Database or Model first development.

To make sure Code First is used, remove `metadata` part of the connection string.

Comment: @OP Since you seem to need to update the connectionstring at runtime, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-16.aspx for further info on how to do that with the DB-First approach.